# How to find foreign key field for navigation property?

Tags: entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

For a given entity I can get all its references by calling

```
var references = dbContext.Entry(entity).References;
```

Now I want to set all references to null.

```
foreach (var reference in references)
{
  reference.CurrentValue = null;
}
context.Update(entity);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But apparently it is not sufficient to set the reference to null, one must set the foreign key property as well. But how to find the foreign key field for a given reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.navigationentry.metadata?view=efcore-3.1) property to get the associated [INavigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.inavigation?view=efcore-3.1), then [ForeignKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.inavigation.foreignkey?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_INavigation_ForeignKey) property to get the associated [IForeignKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.iforeignkey?view=efcore-3.1), then the [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.iforeignkey.properties?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IForeignKey_Properties) property to get the associated properties of type [IProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.iproperty?view=efcore-3.1), and finally the [Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ipropertybase.name?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IPropertyBase_Name) property which can be passed to [Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.property?view=efcore-3.1) method to obtain the associated [PropertyEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.propertyentry?view=efcore-3.1) for manipulating the value.

Putting all that in action:

```cs
var entry = dbContext.Entry(entity);
foreach (var reference in entry.References)
{
    reference.CurrentValue = null;
    foreach (var fkProperty in reference.Metadata.ForeignKey.Properties)
        entry.Property(fkProperty.Name).CurrentValue = null;
}
```

**Update:** In recent EF Core versions the `Metadata` property type has been changed to `INavigationBase` (probably as part of a preparation of skip navigation properties support) which has no `ForeignKey` property, hence you need to manually cast it to the aforementioned `INavigation` interface, e.g.

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
...
foreach (var fkProperty in ((INavigation)reference.Metadata).ForeignKey.Properties)
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this appears to get references where it is the principal side of a relationship, such that it'll give the property `Foo.BarId` and then fail to find it.

Comment: @CaptainPrinny `reference.Metadata.IsDependentToPrincipal()` can be used to identify such reference and skip them if needed.

Comment: It appears the ForeignKey property is missing by EF Core 8 (not sure when it was removed).  Is there a workaround?